# WebDriverWait is terminated before reach to the last page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I scraped review score data from booking.com.  My code is shown as follow with step-by-step explanation

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_random_wait(lower=5, upper=15):
    max_wait = randint(lower, upper)
    waiting_time = randint(lower - 1, max_wait)
    print("waiting for {} seconds".format(waiting_time))
    return waiting_time

name = "Eden The Residence at The Sea"

# Invoke Chrome and go to booking.com
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://booking.com")
print("Accessing " + driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

# Enter hotel name
print("Searching for {}.".format(name))
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class*='sb-searchbox__input']").send_keys(name)

# Click search
print("Clicking search button.")
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()

# Click the hotel name, i.e. Eden the Residence at The Sea
print("Selecting {} from return list.".format(name))
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + name + "')]").click()

# Click to show toggle side bar that store reviews
print("Clicking on review tab.")
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Click to show all reviews
print("Showing all reviews.")
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#show_reviews_tab').click()

# Choose sorting by date from drop-down menu
print("Sorting review by date in descending order.")
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id='review_sort'] "))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Date (newer to older)")

date_reviews = []
score_reviews = []
scrape_data = pd.DataFrame()
page = 1

while True:
    
    try:
        print("Scraping reviews on page {}".format(page))
        # time.sleep(get_random_wait())
        container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='c-review-block']")))
        
        # Extracting dates
        dates = [c.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='c-review-block__row'] > span[class='c-review-block__date']").text.split("Reviewed: ")[-1] for c in container]
        date_reviews = date_reviews + dates
        
        # Extracting scores
        scores = [float(c.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='bui-review-score__badge']").text) for c in container]
        score_reviews = score_reviews + scores
        
        buffer = pd.DataFrame({"date": date_reviews,
                               "score": score_reviews})
        
        scrape_data = pd.concat([scrape_data, buffer], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='pagenext']"))).click()
        
        page += 1
    except Exception:
        scrape_data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(scrape_data["date"], format="%B %d, %Y")
        break
```

With this hotel, the code should click nextpage until the 10th page but it stop at the 8th page.  I could not figure out what went wrong with the code.  May I have your suggestions?

Comment: You don't have `break` condition to stop iteration. Also using `time.sleep` along with WebDriverWait seem to be bad idea - you simply wasting time

Comment: Thank you.   I added break to the code and edit the question about unexplainable behavior again.  Now, the web driver is no longer stuck in the loop but terminate before reach to the last page.

Comment: Try to add `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-current="page"]').text == page)` before clicking Next button

Comment: I added the above command before this line `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='pagenext']"))).click()` but it terminated since the 1st page.  May I know the meaning of adding such a command before clicking next button?

Comment: The meaning is to wait for page to be opened before clicking Next button. You might click it to early. Try to replace `'//a[@aria-current="page"]'` with `'//a[@aria-current="page"]/div[@aria-hidden]'`

Comment: Thank you.  I replaced the Xpath as you suggested but the behavior is still persistent (terminate at the 1st page).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some reviews are hidden by moderators and looks like `"This review is hidden because it doesn't meet our guidelines."`. You cannot extract date or score from these reviews and this is why your code breakes

Try to replace below 2 lines

```
dates = [c.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='c-review-block__row'] > span[class='c-review-block__date']").text.split("Reviewed: ")[-1] for c in container]
scores = [float(c.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='bui-review-score__badge']").text) for c in container]
```

with

```
dates_selector = "div[class='c-review-block__row'] > span[class='c-review-block__date']"
dates = [c.find_element_by_css_selector(dates_selector).text.split("Reviewed: ")[-1] if c.find_elements_by_css_selector(dates_selector) else None for c in container]
score_selector = "div[class='bui-review-score__badge']"
scores = [float(c.find_element_by_css_selector(score_selector).text) if c.find_elements_by_css_selector(score_selector) else None for c in container]
```

In case of hidden review you'll get `None` as date and score (you can of cource set another value)